# Selecting a hierarchy column from the same object

Tags: soql, object, hierarchy

I have a query I've written for the Organization/Account object

`SELECT ID, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, 
       BillingPostalCode,  County__c, Phone, ParentId
FROM Account`

This works fine and returns what I need, however ParentId is a hierarchy column that references the same object - `Account`

I can't seem to figure out a way to write a query that returns the data about the record that ParentId refers to. All I really want is the "Name" associated to that ParentId.

Currently I do a second query and then match the results to each other, but this seems inefficient. Can I do it in pure SOQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where with custom relationship fields you turn `My_Custom_Lookup__c` into `My_Custom_Lookup__r.Some_Field__c` for cross-object SOQL, with standard fields you typically just chop off the `Id` on the end of the field. So here,

```
SELECT Parent.Name FROM Account
```

Or likewise,

```
SELECT Account.Name FROM Case
SELECT Opportunity.Amount FROM OpportunityContactRole
```

where the lookup fields are `AccountId` and `OpportunityId` respectively.